# Meaning of Quotation

Tags: meaning

"The custom and fashion of today will be the awkwardness and outrage of tomorrow"

Answer (score 1):

It means in the future, people looking back at today's things considered fashionable and a part of custom will think of them as outrageous and awkward.

Time goes by, tastes change.

Comment: Time goes **by**, tastes change.

Answer (score 1):

Fashions and habits that are normal now, will in the future be considered stupid or laughable.

Ideology that is morally acceptable today will be seen as completely unacceptable in the future.

Example: Think about trends and customs relating to racial segregation, romantic relationships, the role of women etc that have been considered normal and customary in the past and would now be considered outrageous and unacceptable.